# Add HTML in a Link_to - Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Can I add HTML in a link_to?

For example, instead of `<%= link_to post.title, post %>` I'd prefer:

```
<%= link_to '<span>post.title</span>', post %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I'd like to include `erb` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use block:

```
<%= link_to(post) do %>
  <span>Test</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didn't tried that. I guess you can but what your browser think about that =)

Comment: for sure I've included `image_tag` inside `link_to` block

Answer (score 0):

I would use block as well but general approach is:

```
= link_to '', :href => some_path, :class=> 'some classes', :etc => 'some value' do
  %span your HTML here
```

The same in erb of course.